# TortoiseSVN lists files as modified, but they are identical

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, merge

I am merging a hot fix from our QA branch back into our Dev branch.  Five files have changed.  I do a fresh checkout of the Dev branch.  I then do a merge (range of revisions) from QA into the Dev working copy.  It brings in five files and there is a conflict on an external and ignore property -- which I resolve by "using local" (dev).

When I check modifications or commit, I expect to see the five files I merged as the only changes.  However, I get close to 700 "modified" files showing up in the commit dialog.  If I select one of these files and "Compare with base," WinMerge comes up and says the "files are identical."

I have tried this with the file dates set to "last committed" and not.

- Why are all of these files showing up
  as modified, when they are identical?
- What in the merge is causing this?
- How do I prevent SVN/TortoiseSVN from
  getting confused this way in the
  future?

Comment: Can you describe in detail the external and ignore properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen this behaviour (or similar behaviour at least) following a merge. However, using TortoiseMerge I could see that whilst the file itself had not changed, there was a related *mergeinfo* value that had.

The answers posted to question might provide more insight:

[Is there a way to turn TortoiseSVN using svn:mergeinfo off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622409/tortoisesvn-using-svnmergeinfo-is-there-a-way-to-turn-it-off)

Comment: This indeed is the problem.  I can see the mergeinfo difference now that I am looking for it.  I'll have to study up and see how mergeinfo gets set like that.  I am not sure that I have done a non-root merge.

Answer (score 4):

Is WinMerge ignoring some **whitespace differences**?

Your IDE might be configured to replace some whitespace, maybe the newlines are different (\n -> \r\n) or tabs are being expanded to spaces or vice-versa.