# Subversion Merge: Unchanged file showing as changed

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I do my development in a `development` branch and then merge into `trunk` before creating a tag for release.  I've been finding that one file continually shows up as changed when committing after the merge.  It has not changed.  I am posting this in hope that someone else has experienced the issue and knows what is going on.

**Additional Info:**

- It's a php file, extending the Zend_Db_Table
- It does not show as an incoming change when merging
- The commit dialog lists the file, double-clicking the file to diff shows two different dialogs:

  - svn:mergeinfo

    1. development branch, showing two version ranges and several other version numbers (comma-separated)
    2. trunk, a single version range
  - file diff, with no differences
- The commit status dialog lists the file as modified, but doesn't list it as a "Sending content" item

Comment: What kind of file is it?

Comment: What does the diff show?

Comment: @lod3n & @David - I updated my question to give more detail

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the svn:mergeinfo property which is being updated. See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622409/tortoisesvn-using-svnmergeinfo-is-there-a-way-to-turn-it-off).

To summarize: either ignore it and just commit, or delete the `svn:mergeinfo` property on that one file. And follow the [merging advice in the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.finalword) so that you confine such properties to the root of your project  tree as much as possible.

**update**: This appears to be fixed in SVN 1.7. From the release notes: [reduced subtree mergeinfo changes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#subtree-mergeinfo-recording).

Comment: That sounds like what I'm experiencing!  I must have done a merge on just that file at one point.  I will try your suggestion.  Thanks!

Comment: I have removed the `svn:mergeinfo` property from the file in `development` and `trunk`.  If it solves the issue, I will accept your answer.

Comment: When through the merging process this morning and the file no longer shows up.  Thanks!