# How do you manage your release branch in SVN?

Tags: svn, merge, branch, branching-and-merging, trunk

We use Subversion for our source control system and we do our mainline work in trunk.  When we released our software we created a branch.  When we need to upgrade our release I will merge revision from the trunk into our branch, commit and make a tag.  This approach has made it possible for us to cherry pick a revision or two from the trunk, merge it into the branch and quickly deploy the fix.  However, because I am cherry picking revision numbers, it becomes difficult know what revision have made it into the branch from the trunk.  Is there anyway that I can see which revisions have been merged into the trunk without recording it outside of subversion?

We are using subversion 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you merge to branch with **svn merge** the merged revisions are automatically recorded into **svn:mergeinfo** property. Thus, you can cherry pick revisions to branch

```
cd branch
svn merge -r REV1:REV2 TRUNK_URL
svn commit -m "Cherry picked fix"
```

and check revisions with

```
svn mergeinfo BRANCH_URL
```

output:

```
/trunk:REV1-REV2
```

Check [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo)

Comment: I see how that is done, but I am guessing that because I did the merge with TortoiseSVN and checked "ignore ancestry", that ruined the lineage and svn did not record it in the svn:mergeinfo property.  Is that correct?

Comment: I suppose yes (haven't tried that); found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622409/tortoisesvn-using-svnmergeinfo-is-there-a-way-to-turn-it-off/1280749#1280749

Comment: That was my problem.  Thanks for your help.